# Empty column name while destroying object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two models: Show and Deal.

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deals, :inverse_of => :show, :dependent => :destroy
  ...

class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show, :inverse_of => :deals
  ...
```

When I try to destroy Show I get this error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "deals" WHERE "deals"."" = $1
```

Why is the column name empty? In schema.rb:

```
create_table "deals", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "discount_id"
  t.integer "show_id"
end

create_table "shows", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "movie_id"
  t.integer  "hall_id"
  t.datetime "show_time"
  t.integer  "city_id"
  t.integer  "price"
end
```

Foreign key added to database

```
CONSTRAINT fk_deals_shows FOREIGN KEY (show_id)
  REFERENCES shows (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

**P.S.** I resolved this issue by adding primary key to deals table, but I don't really need it there. So the question is still actual. Can I use dependency with models without an id primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [compositekeys](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/) rails do not support composite primary keys (that is your case). So one of the solutions is to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` as your table seems like just many-to-many table.

The other solution is to use the gem that is located on the link above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure it resolves your issue but according to https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ccea98389abbf150b886c9f964b1def47f00f237 you need to set the `:inverse_of` param with singular value :

```
belongs_to :show, :inverse_of => :deal
```

I hope it helps

Comment: in your example the relation between entities is one-to-one, but in my  case it's one-to-many, so `deals` is right